# My Scrollview is not scrolling with a LinearLayout android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

My Scrollview is not scrolling with a LinearLayout android

any idea why? if so please respond, I recently started on android so it might be really easy thing. But i searched and couldn't fix it. help would be gladly appreciated.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#161616">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/image"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: CardView might steal the touch event

Comment: Is the content height greater than the height of your view screen?

Comment: @NollyJ No, i don't think so.

Comment: @Adrien, You can see  and scroll when the content height is more than the view height since you set your scrollView height to match parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the layout, in portrait there is probably not enough content to even need the view to scroll. I plugged this into Android Studio and was only able to scroll when in landscape.

Also, as a general rule, the child of a `ScrollView` (your `LinearLayout`) should use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

If you want your `ScrollView` to always at least fill the screen, you can use the `android:fillViewPort="true"` attribute on your `ScrollView`.

Comment: Yea, i was planning to add more content in the future.

Comment: Create 2 more identical `CardView`s in your layout and see if it scrolls then.

Comment: thanks, it worked!! i added more cardview and it scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a scrollable view (cardView) inside an another scrollable view (LinearLayout) because both scrolls are incompatible.

If you only have a TextView upper the CardView, I would remove the ScrollView and then the CardView will scroll normally. The layout structure should be:

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView>
<Cardview>
...
</CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.